# how to move to the new view fast in ipad application

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have many view controller when i click on tableView cell it move to new view controller problem is that it takes alot of time to move to the next view may be due to view which is to load fetches data from server here is my code for the view which loads

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {

   appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  UIImageView *bottomImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"]];

   [bottomImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,690,1024,34)];
  [self.view addSubview:bottomImageView];


   UIButton *button1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 2.0, 88, 40.0)];
  [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(loginPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoutN.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button1];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;



self.title=@"Catalog";
popImageView.hidden=YES;
passwordLabel.hidden=YES;
userLabel.hidden=YES;
userNameTextField.hidden=YES;
userPasswordTextField.hidden=YES;
signInButton.hidden=YES;

tableView.hidden=NO;




searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searching = NO;
letUserSelectRow = YES;

if(!categoryArray){



    categoryArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


}

if(!userArray){



    userArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


}
if(!subCategoryArray){


    subCategoryArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

if(!subCategoryArrayOne){


    subCategoryArrayOne =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


}
if(!subCategoryArrayTwo){


    subCategoryArrayTwo =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


}

[self setUpData];
[self setUpDataSub];
[self setUpDataSubOne];
    [self setUpDataSubTwo];
int count=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];
NSLog(@"Arrays Content Are %d",count);
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

is there any way so that view loads fast

Comment: The delay is related to the image load or the data setup? Profile to find out. Then decide if you can run the time consuming code in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not loading fast because of I guess those data set operation in viewDidLoad method . I think those are :

```
[self setUpData];
[self setUpDataSub];
[self setUpDataSubOne];
[self setUpDataSubTwo];
```

The one thing you could do is to move this operations to perform on the background thread . For that move this operations to the separate function and call that to perform on background from the view did load method :

```
-(void)dataOperations
{
[self setUpData];
[self setUpDataSub];
[self setUpDataSubOne];
[self setUpDataSubTwo];
}
```

and in viewDidLoad call this function in background:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(dataOperations) withObject:nil];
```

Or you can directly call those method from viewDidLoad like :

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setUpData) withObject:nil];
```